# Operator Overloading Insertion

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, cin, cout

**What is Problem Here. It is not working as an expected.**

**I want that << (insertion) Work For both cout and cin.**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
private:
   string name;
   int age;
   unsigned long int salary; 
public:
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ,a );
   friend istream& operator << (istream& ,a );
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& dout,a a1){
   cout<<"Name = "<< a1.name<<"Age = "<<a1.age<<"Salary = "<<a1.salary<<end;
   return dout;
}
istream& operator << (istream& din,a& a1){
   cout<<"Enter Your Name , Age  , Salary .....Press Enter To Seperate New Value"<<end;
   cin>>a1.name>>a1.age>>a1.salary;
}
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   a a1;

   cin<<a1;
   cout<<a1;
   return 0;
}
```

Error is too long.
->[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: Note that the arrows go left (`<<`) for output and right (`>>`) for input... Look at the functions you have written.

Comment: The error comes from `end`, you probably meant `endl`. But... huh? What are you trying to achieve here? You should definitely rethink your operator overloading.

Comment: Thank you Friends. I did very silly mistakes. endl, parameter in function declaration , return type. Now only problem is that friend function not able to access private member.  @Yksisarvinen

Comment: Your operators should read and write to their respective stream arguments, not to `cin` and `cout`. They should also normally not interact with the user.

Comment: @molbdnilo i create this so it wan't confuse user that he /she is using cin/cout with premitive or non premitive datatype.

Comment: @thesummer - I rolled back your edits since in your edits you changed the code and changed the compiler error that you are getting. My answer fixes the issues in the original code and explains what those issues were so that the code will now compile.  Please don't change your question to a new question after people have answered. If you have a new problem then ask a new question.

Comment: @pstrjds sorry i am new here

Comment: @thesummer - No problem. That is why I added the explanation of why I rolled back your edits.

Comment: @thesummer I would be *very* surprised if  `std::ofstream o(”log.txt”); a x; o << x << 12;` prints `x` on standard output and 12 in the file, or if `std::ifstream i(”data.txt”); a x; int y; i << x >> y;` first reads `x` from stdin and then an `int` from the file.

Comment: i don't get what do you mean  . but i think it can cause so many problems @molbdnilo

Comment: @thesummer - I believe @molbnilo's point is that what you are trying to do violates the "Law of Least Surprise", both because you are overloading `<<` for `istream` and because you are reading and writing to std::cin and std::cout in your stream operator overloads (as per the code posted) rather than reading and writing to the stream arguments provided to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure WHY you want to do this, but it is possible.  Just remember that simply because you can do something does not mean that you SHOULD do that thing (see [C++ Faq Law of Least Surprise](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#law-of-least-surprise-op-ov).
Aside from violating the law of least surprise, you can do what you are trying to do, your code just has several simple compile errors in it that once fixed will work just fine (see [here](https://ideone.com/t2rSI3) for working example).

Here are the changes to make it compile:

```
friend istream& operator << (istream& ,a& ); // Note the addition of the &

// Here the variabe is dout, so change to dout. I also added some spacing
ostream& operator << (ostream& dout,a a1){
   dout<<"Name = "<< a1.name<<" Age = "<<a1.age<<" Salary = "<<a1.salary<<endl;
   return dout;
}

// Here you are using din, so you need to change to din, also you had end instead of endl
istream& operator << (istream& din,a& a1){
    cout<<"Enter Your Name , Age  , Salary .....Press Enter To Seperate New Value"<<endl;
    din>>a1.name>>a1.age>>a1.salary;
    return din;
}
```

Just so the complete code is also in one easy place for you.  Here is your entire program with the changes to make it compile.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
private:
   string name;
   int age;
   unsigned long int salary; 
public:
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ,a );
   friend istream& operator << (istream& ,a& );
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& dout,a a1){
   dout << "Name = "<< a1.name <<" Age = "<< a1.age <<" Salary = "<< a1.salary << endl;
   return dout;
}
istream& operator << (istream& din,a& a1){
   cout <<"Enter Your Name , Age  , Salary .....Press Enter To Seperate New Value" << endl;
   din >> a1.name >> a1.age >> a1.salary;
   return din;
}
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   a a1;

   cin<<a1;
   cout<<a1;
   return 0;
}
```

Now, if we want to follow the Law of Least surprise, then we would change the `istream` operator overload to use `>>` instead of `<<` and move the console text out of the `>>` operator overload and just present it to the user before reading the values.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
private:
   string name;
   int age;
   unsigned long int salary; 
public:
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ,a );
   friend istream& operator >> (istream& ,a& );
};

// Note - Changed variable 'dout' to 'os' for clarity 
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, a a1){
   os << "Name = " << a1.name << " Age = " << a1.age << " Salary = "<< a1.salary << endl;
   return os;
}

// Changed variable from 'din' to 'is' for clarity
istream& operator >> (istream& is,a& a1){
   is >> a1.name >> a1.age >> a1.salary;
   return is;
}

main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   a a1;

   cout << "Enter Your Name , Age  , Salary .....Press Enter To Seperate New Value" << endl;    
   cin >> a1;
   cout << a1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You sir i did wrong declaration of function. Now only problem is that friend  function not able to access private member. @pstrjds

Comment: @thesummer - The code linked over at ideone is a working example of your code as posted in the question. I fixed each of the compiler errors including the issue of not being able to access the private member.  If you replace the functions with the ones I have listed in the answer it should compile.